# Java Socket - Server doesn't respond

Tags: java, sockets, client-server

I have a problem with `Socket` in Java. I would like to send `username` from CLIENT to SERVER.

On SERVER, I'm checking there should not be any other user with the same `username`.

**usernames are stored in HashMap**.

I am sending message from SERVER to CLIENT depending upon the below conditions

**If user exists with the same name:**

> Duplicated username. Try again

**If user not exists:**

> OK

Client side verifying which message we are getting is it **OK or not**.

The problem is when I am sending message from SERVER, CLIENT doesn't receive any message.

**Client.java**

```
System.out.println("Enter nickname: ");            
while(response == null || !response.equals("OK")) { 
    message = br.readLine(); // reading from standard input
    out.println(message);
    out.flush();
    response = in.readLine(); // here client is waiting for return message
    System.out.println(response);
}
```

**Server.java**

```
    username = input.readLine();
    while(clientOutputs.containsKey(username)) {
       output.write("Duplicated username. Try again: ");
       output.flush(); 
       username = input.readLine();
    } 
    output.write("OK");
    output.flush(); 
    clientOutputs.put(username, output);
```

Comment: On the server side, maybe you should add a line break to your written String, or use a `PrintWriter` and its `println` method, as you probably do on the client side .

Comment: @Berger Thank you so much! I used PrintWriter on the server side, but I don't know why I used write function instead of println.

Answer (score 0):

You're reading lines but you aren't writing lines. Add a line terminator to the OK message, and all others from that source.